# how to dynamically build inventory and vars file and use inside ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

Currently i have inventory file and services vars file are static but would like to be dynamically passed as order of execution changes most of the times. I thought jinja template would be a better suited here but need help with that.

inventory file:-

```
/inventory/PROD/hosts.ini

[primary]
PRI123.example.com
PRI333.exacmple.com
[secondary]
SEC123.example.com
SEC345.example.com

/vars/primaryservices.yml
---
services:
  - RSAservice1
  - RSAservice2
  - RSAservice3

/vars/secondaryservices.yml
---
services:
  - RSAsecservice1
  - RSAsecservice2
  - RSAsecservice3
```

My windows start service playbook is start_windows_services.yml which is

```
---
- name: windows services start
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

tasks:
  - name: include primay app service lists
    include_vars:
       file: ../varsp/rimaryservices.yml
  - name: start primary app services
    win_service:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      state: started
    loop: " {{ services }} "
    when: inventory_hostname in groups['primary']

  - name: include secondary app server lists
    include_vars:
       file: ../vars/secondaryservices.yml
  - name: start secondary app services
    win_service:
      name: "{{ item }}"
      start: started
    loop: " {{ services }} "
    when inventory_hostname in groups['secondary']
```

Answer (score 1):

See:

- [Organizing host and group variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables)
- [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)

---

Put the variables into the directory **group_vars**. For example, *inventory/prod/group_vars* (precedence 6.)

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── inventory
│   └── prod
│       ├── group_vars
│       │   ├── primary
│       │   │   └── services.yml
│       │   └── secondary
│       │       └── services.yml
│       └── hosts
└── pb.yml
```

```ini
shell> cat inventory/prod/hosts 
[primary]
pri_123
pri_333
[secondary]
sec_123
sec_345
```

```yaml
shell> cat inventory/prod/group_vars/primary/services.yml 
services:
  - RSAservice1
  - RSAservice2
  - RSAservice3
```

```yaml
shell> cat inventory/prod/group_vars/secondary/services.yml 
services:
  - RSAsecservice1
  - RSAsecservice2
  - RSAsecservice3
```

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: all

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: services|to_yaml
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i inventory/prod pb.yml 

PLAY [all] ************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [pri_123] => 
  services|to_yaml: |-
    [RSAservice1, RSAservice2, RSAservice3]
ok: [pri_333] => 
  services|to_yaml: |-
    [RSAservice1, RSAservice2, RSAservice3]
ok: [sec_345] => 
  services|to_yaml: |-
    [RSAsecservice1, RSAsecservice2, RSAsecservice3]
ok: [sec_123] => 
  services|to_yaml: |-
    [RSAsecservice1, RSAsecservice2, RSAsecservice3]

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
pri_123: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
pri_333: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
sec_123: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
sec_345: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Now, you can start the services in a single task

```yaml
    - name: start app services
      win_service:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        start: started
      loop: "{{ services }}"
```

---

Warning: The concept of *group_vars* works if there are no intersections among the groups. The variable *services* will be overridden for common hosts in alphabetical order of the groups' names. For example, the inventory

```ini
shell> cat inventory/prod/hosts
[primary]
host_123
pri_333
[secondary]
host_123
sec_345
```

would give

```yaml
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [host_123] => 
  services|to_yaml: |-
    [RSAsecservice1, RSAsecservice2, RSAsecservice3]
ok: [sec_345] => 
  services|to_yaml: |-
    [RSAsecservice1, RSAsecservice2, RSAsecservice3]
ok: [pri_333] => 
  services|to_yaml: |-
    [RSAservice1, RSAservice2, RSAservice3]
```

See: [How variables are merged](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#how-variables-are-merged)

Comment: I tried the above but got "unexpected failure during module execution" error,   My tree structure is [ /inventory/prod/group_vars/primaryappstart/services.yml] and so on.  My playbook is
---
- name: test
   hosts: all

   tasks: 
     - debug:
           var: services|to_yaml